# Nodatime BclDateTimeZone EqualsImpl throws NotImplementedException

Tags: c#, nodatime

The `EqualsImpl` method in the Nodatime `BclDateTimeZone` class throws a `NotImplementedException`. It is documented to behave in this way - is there a reason for this?

If testing equality of two `ZonedDateTime`s that use a `BclDateTimeZone` this causes the exception to be thrown.

Is this a bug, it doesn't seem right?

Comment: Throwing a `NotImplementedException` is definitely not a _bug_, especially if it's documented.

Comment: It is not documented that my `ZonedDateTime` can throw an exception when checking equality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is documented to behave in this way - is there a reason for this?

Yup - it's basically very hard to determine zone equality in a general way. Suppose we have two `BclDateTimeZone` instances which wrap two distinct `TimeZoneInfo` values... we could:

- Say they're not equal arbitrarily, even if they are *logically* equivalent
- Compare them by ID (impossible in the PCL which doesn't support IDs, and broken under Mono why `TimeZoneInfo.Local` has an ID of `Local` IIRC)
- Compare them for equality through history, which is very costly

I agree that it's a pain, and I think I'm planning on removing value equality on `ZonedDateTime` entirely in Noda Time 2.0, and make `ZonedDateTime` use reference equality.

If you *want* to compare time zones, a better alternative is likely to be the use of [`ZonedEqualityComparer`](http://nodatime.org/1.3.x/api/html/T_NodaTime_TimeZones_ZoneEqualityComparer.htm) to specify how you want them to be compared.

But the inability to compare `ZonedDateTime` values for equality when using BCL values is definitely nasty. I've [raised a bug](https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/issues/detail?id=334) for that; I'm preparing a 1.3.1 release, and I might see if I can fix it there, rather than you having to wait for 2.0.

Comment: Also, consider that if you compare by ID, you also have the possibility of `TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id) != TimeZoneInfo.Local` because DST might be disabled in the Windows control panel.  (Soooo frustrating!)

Comment: @MattJohnson: Wow, had entirely forgotten about that possibility. Thanks for bringing it up. I'm not sure how this can be fixed in a backwardly-compatible way, to be honest... comparing the `TimeZoneInfo` references might be the least-worst option for 1.3.1...

Comment: Not sure if it will ever work for `Local`.  [See comments here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/timezoneinfo.cs,151)

Comment: @MattJohnson: Right... so it would work between two calls using Local, but not between a call using Local and one using the equivalent original zone. That may be livable-with for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

After trying to write failing unit tests to prove this bug, I found it difficult to replicate.

Comparing `ZonedDateTime`s that have `BclDateTimeZone`s on different offsets is not an issue. 
Comparing `ZonedDateTime`s with different `LocalDateTime`s is not an issue.

I could see from the source that the comparison of `ZonedDateTime` `Zone` only came into play if the `LocalDateTime` and `Offset` were equal.

My problem arose where I was using two different references of `BclDateTimeZone` on the same offset. I did this by using `DateTimeZoneProviders.Bcl.GetSystemDefault()` in one place and `BclDateTimeZone.ForSystemDefault()` in another. Needless to say, they are now calling into common code.

I have this failing test where I am comparing two `ZonedDateTime`s with different `DateTimeZone`s on the same offset:

```
ZonedDateTime dtzOne = new ZonedDateTime(Instant.FromUtc(2014, 11, 11, 21, 00), DateTimeZoneProviders.Bcl.GetZoneOrNull("Greenwich Standard Time"));
ZonedDateTime dtzTwo = new ZonedDateTime(Instant.FromUtc(2014, 11, 11, 21, 00), DateTimeZoneProviders.Bcl.GetZoneOrNull("GMT Standard Time"));

Assert.That(dtzOne, Is.Not.EqualTo(dtzTwo));
```

This test throws an exception here:

```
System.NotImplementedException : The method or operation is not implemented.
   at NodaTime.TimeZones.BclDateTimeZone.EqualsImpl(DateTimeZone zone)
   at NodaTime.DateTimeZone.Equals(DateTimeZone obj)
   at NodaTime.ZonedDateTime.Equals(ZonedDateTime other)
```

I can easily work around this issue, but it is probably worth fixing.